# VC++ macro definition ## operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, preprocessor

I am trying to port our solution from VS2010 to VS2017 and have hit this compilation error with the macro definition involving token pasting operator. Here is the code below

```
#include “stdafx.h”

#define TEST_MACRO(str)    \
{                                             \
     _T(“Error”) ## str ## _T(“\””);      \
}

int main()
{
    TEST_MACRO(“ check “);
     return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine in VS2010 but fails in VS2017/VS2015. It doesn’t seem to recognize _T(“\””) following str ##. I am using “multi byte character set” and hence _T(x) resolves to x ( in tchar.h ).

Can someone help me understand this issue?

Comment: for what you use `_T`  at all ?

Comment: Is it because you are using the “ char - replace with "  Also you might need to #include <tchar.h> for the _T

Comment: what is sense of this macro at all ? what you try get ?

Comment: @Bathsheba - say this for microsoft. this is standard windows macro. exist large count of another such (leading underscore followed by a capital letter) macros and symbols

Comment: @RbMm: So long as you don't *define* it yourself, it's fine. Yes, didn't read the code in the question carefully enough. My bad.

Comment: @Bathsheba - really in practic **all** standard windows types uses leading underscore followed by a capital letter scheme. :) (`_STARTUPINFOW`, `_LIST_ENTRY`, .. almost all)

Comment: This code is invalid and 2010 has lots of bugs. These two factors just cancel each other. To fix, you don't need any concatenation operator to concatenate string literals, `"x" "y" "z"` is the same as `"xyz"`. (Use the same kind of literals when concatenating, either all wide or all narrow).

Comment: I works fine in VS 2010 because there are no user defined literals there. About VS 2017, please, see my answer. The notes about concatenation are also ok

Comment: @RbMm it's an atavistic remnant of Windows 95 technology. There's no real reason to use it today.

Comment: @n.m. "(Use the same kind of literals when concatenating, either all wide or all narrow)". Can you explain why this is required?

Comment: This is in fact not required, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
#define TEST_MACRO(str) \
{                                  \
     _T("Error") _T(str) _T("\""); \
}
```

Using `##` you concatеnate your strings and for compiler it looks like: `_T("Error")" check "_T("\"")`. And `" check "_T` is a problem here. It is an user defined literal `_T` which is undefined

Comment: Thank you @Lex Sergeev. This solved the issue. Also using this expression with ## operator also seems to work fine. _T("Error") ##  _T(str) ## _T("\"").

Comment: Why is `_T("Error") ## _T(str) ## _T("\"")` not an issue? _T(str) gets preprocessed to str which is "check", so the compiler should still see `" check "_T`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `##`. Concatenating string literals is pointless.

`"foo" "bar" "baz"` is equivalent to `"foobarbaz"`.

Answer (score 0):

More likely it's stuck on the left double sharp as it tries to concatenate a closing parenthesis and `str` to produce a token. Have you tried to remove it?

```
#define TEST_MACRO(str) { _T(“Error”) str ## _T(“\””); }
```